# How do I determine the source of tons of TASKLET IRQs?

Tags: linux, debian, irq

I've got one CPU pinned at 100%, though not always the same CPU.  It looks like it's getting absolutely hammered with TASKLET IRQs.  How can I track down their source? I'm on Debian 12.  This happens immediately on boot, before opening anything user-facing beyond i3

Additional info:

- htop shows 100% use between `kworker/3:1+pm` and `ksoftirqd/3` (when CPU 3 is maxed - the number always matches the maxed CPU)
- `irqtop -s` shows:

```
fmwk - irqtop - 2023-07-09 09:06:21 -0500
              CPU0   CPU1   CPU2   CPU3   CPU4   CPU5   CPU6   CPU7
  cpuUtil:     2.4    1.0    1.0  100.0    1.4    1.6    1.2    2.6   total CPU utilization %
     %irq:     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   hardware IRQ CPU util%
    %sirq:     0.6    0.0    0.2    3.8    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   software IRQ CPU util%
 irqTotal:     144     62    649   1296     76    111     99     63   total hardware IRQs
s   TIMER:       8      2     44     29     13     21      8     15
s  NET_RX:       0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
s TASKLET:       0      0      0 331119      0      0      0      0
s   SCHED:     122     42    105     19     46     75     59     33
s     RCU:      17     14     19     22      9     17     13      8
```

- my `XF86RFKill` key seems to make it move to another CPU.  This happens when turning it off or on, so twice for a complete rfkill on/off cycle and continuing while everything is killed and nothing is plugged into the laptop.
- I'm using a Framework with an 11th-gen intel board, and the issue continues with all modules removed
- The behavior continues after a sleep/wake cycle
- The behavior usually continues after `systemctl reboot`
- The behavior does not usually start on a cold boot
- A sleep/wake cycle or rfkill on/off cycle does not seem to cause it if the issue is not already occurring